# Which SIP server to deploy for my Android VoIP app?

Tags: android, sip, voip, instant-messaging, lync

I am building an android application that supports VoIP/IM/Presence with the available Android SIP stack. I also need to deploy a SIP server to enable the mentioned SIP functionalities as part of my project.

Developing the Android app seems easy with all the available resources and abundant source codes online. However, I am seriously stuck with deploying a SIP server to communicate with the app.

I experimented for around a month with OpenSIPS but it seemed a bit advanced to my level. Especially that it is runs on a linux environment.

1. Any suggestions for other easy-to-deploy and easy-to-deal-with SIP servers?
2. I haven't done extensive research on this yet, but what do you think of Microsoft Lync Server for that purpose?

Comment: [Asterisk](http://www.asterisk.org/) maybe?

Comment: @Jasmine... i have the same issue. May you please suggest me in simple how you have solved this. I need to implement SIP with VOIP with iOS devices. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @singhSan I'm really sorry for my late reply, I just got to see your comment. I have used TrixBox (an implementation of Asterisk). It installs with all the required configurations and all you have to do is add your extensions (users) to the system to get it up and running from the web interface. I hope my answer helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Cthulu suggested in the comments, I suggest trying out [Asterisk](http://www.asterisk.org/). Only a few files (sip.conf and extensions.conf IIRC) need to be configured to have it up and listening for calls.

There's also an excellent free book that will help with terminology and configuration when just starting out. The book can be read in full [online](http://www.asteriskdocs.org/). You can also download a [PDF version from O'Reilly](http://cdn.oreilly.com/books/9780596510480.pdf).

There are also many flavours of Asterisk that have somewhat simplified interfaces to make setup easier for the first time. [AsteriskNow](http://www.asterisk.org/downloads/asterisknow) can be downloaded directly from Digium (the company that's responsible for the Asterisk project). If you are going to be doing more SIP work in the future, it might be worth it to use 'real' Asterisk, but if this is a one time thing, try out AsteriskNow.

The other main project to investigate would be [Freeswitch](http://www.freeswitch.org/), though I find the Asterisk setup to be a little more straightforward.

Comment: Thanks for the response!
So far I have looked up Asterisk, and I found a lot of projects based on it. I am not sure whether to choose OpenFire, TrixBox or AsteriskNOW. 
I am really looking for an easy-to-install software with a large support community, so it wouldn't take much of my time and I would be able to focus on the app more :)

Comment: Hi Jasmine. Unfortunately, I don't have a lot of experience with the Asterisk 'distros'. However, a quick search did bring me to Amatix Instant PBX: http://amatisoft.com/egroupware/sitemgr/sitemgr-site/?page_name=AmatixInstantPBX Burn the ISO to a CD, and then boot your computer from it to turn it into an Asterisk box. Many other Bootable Asterisk Versions here: http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+Bootable+CDROM

Comment: Thanks Dan! Sorry for the late reply. I have used TrixBox and it works great.